# Synchronize multiple asynchronous results

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application that uses a service to populate an array to use in a table, but the results need a second transformation before they are ready for presentation. I'm calling another service to do so, but how so I know when I am completely finished with all transformations before I alert the UI that I'm finished? I tried this (naive approach) but it has a flaw:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(result => {
  result['entries'].forEach(entry => {
    let fieldToTransform = entry['fieldToTransform'];
    this.transformService.transform(fieldToTransform).subscribe(transformedField => {
      entry['fieldToTransform'] = transformedField;
    });// hmm, can't alert UI here
  });// not here either
});
```

But it's pretty clear that each iteration of the loop will call the service and will finish at different times. How can I know when they are all done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid multiple subscriptions if you can help it. In this case, I think you can.

I hope this example make sense. There are many ways/operators to achieve variations of what you need. I used `concatMap()`, `toArray()`, `map()` in the example below. This example assumes that your second async service call always return 1 value.

```
// simulates first async service call
const sourceOne = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
// simulates second async service call
const sourceTwo = Rx.Observable.of('something-from-two');

// for each value from source one, process it after getting a value from source two
const example = sourceOne.concatMap(sourceOneValue => {
  return sourceTwo.map(sourceTwoValue => '---' + sourceOneValue + ':' + sourceTwoValue + '---')
})

// as separate values
example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
// as a single array
// example.toArray().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See this [runnable example](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=const%20sourceOne%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.of%281%2C2%2C3%29%3B%0Aconst%20sourceTwo%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.of%28%27something-from-two%27%29%3B%0Aconst%20example%20%3D%20sourceOne.concatMap%28sourceOneValue%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20sourceTwo.map%28sourceTwoValue%20%3D%3E%20%27---%27%20%2B%20sourceOneValue%20%2B%20%27%3A%27%20%2B%20sourceTwoValue%20%2B%20%27---%27%29%0A%7D%29%0A%2F%2F%20as%20separate%20values%0Aexample.subscribe%28val%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28val%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20as%20a%20single%20array%0A%2F%2F%20example.toArray%28%29.subscribe%28val%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28val%29%29%3B%0A%0A) and tweak to meet your needs.

This is actually a question about RxJS, and I recommend further reading on that topic to meet your specific use case if the example is not sufficient.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. How will I adjust this if one observable has a dependency on the elements of the array? E.g. sourceTwo's observable required an input from sourceOne's elements.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your second, nested `Observable` subscription, you have results from both of your calls.

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(result => {
  result['entries'].forEach(entry => {
    let fieldToTransform = entry['fieldToTransform'];
    this.transformService.transform(fieldToTransform).subscribe(transformedField => {
      entry['fieldToTransform'] = transformedField;
      // <<< --- maybe here? you have results from both of your service methods
    });// hmm, can't alert UI here
  });// not here either
});
```

Edit:

Then you should probably use some kind of merging Observable operator.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html @`Combining Observables`

Here is an example (I can not verify it right now, but maybe it can help give you an idea):

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(result => {
  let transformSubscriptions = [];

  result['entries'].forEach(entry => {

    let fieldToTransform = entry['fieldToTransform'];

    const sub = this.transformService.transform(fieldToTransform)
      .do(transformedField => {
        entry['fieldToTransform'] = transformedField;
      })

    transformSubscriptions.push(sub);
  });

  Observable.combineLatest(transformSubscriptions)
    .subscribe(results => window.alert('All transfers happened (at least once)'));
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give me a bunch of alerts since this is called for every element of the loop? When I get the first one, that would mean that I just finished the fastest one, not all of them.

Comment: Oh, so you want to alert your UI just once after you get an array of results from your `dataService` and transformations on all items completes?

Comment: Yes, I would like to wait until everything is ready for presentation.